# What exactly does a return statement do in C#?

Tags: c#, return, return-value, return-type

It's hard for me to grasp what exactly a return statement is doing. For instance, in this method...

```
    public int GivePoints(int amount)
    {
        Points -= amount;
        return amount;
    }
```

Even if I place any random integer after return, the GivePoints method still does the exact same thing. So what is it that the return statement is doing?

Comment: I'm unsure how to answer this question other than to say that it *returns* a value to the caller method.

Answer (score 5):

Return will exit the function when calling it. Whatever is below the return statement in this code block will thus not be executed.

Basically, `return` indicates that whatever operation the function was supposed to perform has been preformed, and passes the result of this operation back (if applicable) to the caller.

Answer (score 5):

`Return` will always exit (leave) the function, anything after return will not execute.

**Return example:**

```
public int GivePoints(int amount)
{
    Points -= amount;
    return; //this means exit the function now.
}
```

**Return a variable example:**

```
public int GivePoints(int amount)
{
    Points -= amount;
    return amount; //this means exit the function and take along 'amount'
}
```

**Return a variable example and catch the variable that got returned:**

```
public int GivePoints(int amount)
{
    Points -= amount;
    return amount; //this means exit the function and take along 'amount'
}

int IamCatchingWhateverGotReturned = GivePoints(1000); //catch the returned variable (in our case amount)
```

Comment: The first example should fail to compile (function must return int value)

Answer (score 3):

`return` will return control from the current method to the caller, and also pass back whatever argument is sent with it.  In your example, `GivePoints` is defined to return an integer, and to accept an integer as an argument. In your example, the value returned is actually the same as the argument value.

A returned value is used from somewhere else in your code that calls the defined method, `GivePoints` in this example.

```
int currentPoints = GivePoints(1);
```

would mean that `currentPoints` gets assigned the value of 1.

What this breaks down to is that `GivePoints` is evaluated. The evaluation of `GivePoints` is based on what the method returns. `GivePoints` returns the input, thus, `GivePoints` will evaluate to 1 in the above example.

Comment: +1 Another good thing to mention might be the `Stack` concept: that methods are invoked on a stack, and a `return` statement exits the current method, returning control flow (and usually a value) back to the previous method on the stack.

Comment: Also, no code that appears after the return statement is run will be evaluated. That's why your "random integer" value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In you example, the function is returning the exact number you are sending to it. In this case, whatever value you pass as `amount`. Therefore, the return in your current code is a bit pointless.

So in your example:

```
int x = GivePoints(1000);
```

x will equal 1000

Comment: You should've explained that anything after return will not execute, which seems to be the questioner's true conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess for your original goal

```
public int GivePoints(int amount)
{
    Points -= amount;
    return Points;
}
```

so return will return the updated value of Points

if this is not your case the code should be

```
public void GivePoints(int amount)
{
    Points -= amount;
}
```