# Can I ask some questions about C# ? (Array)(Loop)

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return

I'm studying C# programming. 
Nevertheless, I don't know how to solve these problems.

Like *(Write a MyAvg method that gets 3 different double inputs and calculates the average of them. It should return the average as the output. Use the function in one simple program)*

```cs
using System;
/*4. Write a MyAvg method that gets 3 different double inputs and calculates the average of them. It should return the average as the output. Use the function in one simple program*/
namespace ConsoleApp36
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                double a, b, c;
                double avg = 0;

                Console.Write("Input the first value : ");
                a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input the second value : ");
                b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Input the third value : ");
                c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                avg = (a + b + c) / 3;
                Console.WriteLine("Average of 3 different values is : {0}", avg);
            }

        }
    }
```

and

*(Write a MyFact function that gets one integer as an input and calculates the factorial of it. It returns factorial as the result of the function. Use the function in one simple program. Use the function in one simple program.)*

```cs
using System;
/*4. Write a MyAvg method that gets 3 different double inputs and calculates the average of them. It should return the average as the output. Use the function in one simple program*/
namespace ConsoleApp39
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, f = 1, num;

            Console.Write("Input the number : ");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
                f = f * i;

            Console.Write("The Factorial of {0} is: {1}\n", num, f);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Have you tried it on your own? It is easier to help if you have something written already.

Comment: yes I tried.. but I don't understand What MyAvg and MyFact means

Comment: It is just a names of the methods you have to write. Like `public int MyFact(int input)`

Comment: Hi Seoyoung, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, SO wants a bit more specific and *actual problematic* questions, as the basic learning of C#, .NET, and whatnot, is probably more suited for a teaching context than a Q&A website. However, are you aware that there is a whole set of chat rooms attached to Stack Overflow? These are a bit more laid back and accepting of more "loose questions". You should ask in the C# chat room, found [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c).

Comment: I put some my own code.. But I still don't know how to make method of Myfact and Myavg ( and What means 'Return'?)

Comment: You have 95% of the answer, just read up on what a "method" is in the context of C#

Comment: I solve this problem!!!! thank you guys XD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be more clear with your questions and show us that you actually tried to write some code. Anyways, here `MyAvg` and `MyFact` is just abbreviations for **"MyAvarage"** and **"MyFactorial"**.

As you should know, average avarage in mathematics is simply summing **n** numbers, and then dividing the sum with **n**. So you should implement it in your function `MyAvg`. Here is how you should take the avarage of three double numbers;

```
double average = (a + b + c) / 3;
```

Also, for the function `MyFact`, you should be taking an int parameter, and then simply be implying the factorial algorithm. Let's assume you've sent **5** as a parameter to `MyFact()`, then you should be multiplying the number **5** decreasingly in a for loop, such as **5*4*3*2*1**, and it will give you the result. You can return this result, or simply print it directly in function.

[For loop to calculate factorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583665/for-loop-to-calculate-factorials)

Comment: I put some my own code.. But I still don't know how to make method of Myfact and Myavg ( and What means 'Return'?)

Comment: Check this question for return; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237649/what-exactly-does-a-return-statement-do-in-c

Comment: I solve this problem!! thank you!!

Comment: If my asnwer helped you, you can check it by simply clicking on the **check** button .